# Async generation of large buffers of random numbers on the GPU

Tags: c, random, pthreads, cuda, c11

I would like to obtain some feedback on a simple code I wrote to
implement an easy and hopefully fast way to generate a large number of floats
with CURAND and use them one at a time.

This is achieved by switching between two large buffers that get generated and copied onto host memory asyncronously while the other buffer is used by the main program.

I tried to implement a naive lock system in order to ensure that the buffers may get reused only when they have been filled by newly generated numbers.

The code seems to work, but at the present stage I am not convinced about the performance of it, with particular emphasis on the `getrandom` function, which in my original intent was meant to be extremely fast 99,9999% of the time when no generation has to be started.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include "threads.h"

#define CUDA_CALL(x) do { if((x)!=cudaSuccess) { \
    printf("Error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__ ,__LINE__);\
    return EXIT_FAILURE ;}} while (0)

#define CURAND_CALL(x) do { if((x)!=CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS) { \
    printf("Error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__ ,__LINE__);\
    return EXIT_FAILURE ;}} while (0)


//                123456789  -> 4 bytes -> 4 gigabytes
#define bufsize  1000000000ul

thrd_t thrd[2];

int* foo;

float *devbuff , *hostbuffONE, *hostbuffTWO;

size_t i; 

curandGenerator_t gen;

int currentbuffer; // 1 -> buffONE, 2 -> buffTWO
unsigned long int counter=1;



int lock=0;


int genONE(void* arg);
int genONE(void* arg)
    {
      CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, devbuff, bufsize));
      CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(hostbuffONE , devbuff , bufsize*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
      lock=0;
      return(0);
    }


int genTWO(void* arg);
int genTWO(void* arg)
    {
      CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, devbuff, bufsize));
      CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(hostbuffTWO , devbuff , bufsize*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
      lock=0;
      return(0);
    }
    

static inline float getrandom();
float getrandom()
    {
        switch (currentbuffer)
        {
            case 1:
                if (counter==bufsize-1)
                    {
                        currentbuffer=2;
                        if (lock==0)
                            {
                                lock=1;
                                thrd_create(&thrd[0], genONE, foo);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                // wait for lock release
                                // on thread 2 
                                thrd_join(thrd[1], 0);
                                lock=1;
                                thrd_create(&thrd[0], genONE, foo);
                            }

                        counter=1;
                        return(hostbuffTWO[0]);
            
                    }
                else{
                       counter++;
                       return(hostbuffONE[counter]);
                    }
          default:
                if (counter==bufsize-1)
                    {
                        currentbuffer=1;
                        if (lock==0)
                            {
                                lock=1;
                                thrd_create(&thrd[1], genTWO, 0);
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                // wait for lock release
                                // on thread 1 
                                thrd_join(thrd[0], 0);
                                lock=1;
                                thrd_create(&thrd[1], genTWO, 0);
                            }
                        counter=1;
                        return(hostbuffONE[0]);
                    }
                else{
                counter++;
                return(hostbuffTWO[counter]);
                }
        }
    }

int main(){

     CURAND_CALL(curandCreateGenerator(&gen,CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT));
     CURAND_CALL(curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen,1234ULL));

     CUDA_CALL(cudaMallocHost((void **)&hostbuffONE, bufsize*sizeof(float)));
     CUDA_CALL(cudaMallocHost((void **)&hostbuffTWO, bufsize*sizeof(float)));
     CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void **)&devbuff, bufsize*sizeof(float)));

     CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, devbuff, bufsize));
     CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(hostbuffONE , devbuff ,    bufsize*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

     CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, devbuff, bufsize));
     CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(hostbuffTWO , devbuff , bufsize*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

     currentbuffer=1; counter=0;


     unsigned long long int ite;
     float useless;

     for (ite=0;ite<(10*bufsize);ite++)
         {
            useless=getrandom();
            if (i%1000000000lu==0)
                {
                    //printf("%f\n",useless);
                    useless=useless-1.0;
                }
        }


// checks we are out of the generating loops
thrd_join(thrd[1], 0);
thrd_join(thrd[0], 0);

CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(devbuff));
CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(hostbuffONE));
CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(hostbuffTWO));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: May you please format your program in an appropriate way? It makes no joy to look at this. PS why do you use a switch for your `getrandom()`? PPS why are you declaring `int genONE(void* arg);` and `int genTWO(void* arg);`

Comment: @paladin sorry for getting back to you so late. I have tried my best to reformat the code appearance, but I am not too informed in this subject. I am declaring two functions to separate the generation on the two buffers, but it's not optimal